# «Слитное/раздельное написание» vs «Слитное/Раздельное написание»

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, косая-черта

В справочнике Лопатина второе слово, которое написано после слеша (*раздельное*), пишется в этом заголовке с маленькой буквы ([Слитное/раздельное написание ***не***](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=79#pp79)).
Однако я считаю, что правильно его писать с большой, т. к. после слеша по логике надо писать второе слово тоже с большой, если первое с большой из-за первой позиции в предложении написано-таки.

Можете, пожалуйста, сказать, как правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: *Слитное/раздельное написание **не***.

> **§ 114.** Сфера применения знака **/** (косая черта) — научная и деловая речь. Он употребляется в следующих функциях.
> **1.** В функции, близкой к союзам *и* и *или*, как знак альтернативности понятий или обозначения единого сложного понятия...
> **2.** Для обозначения отношения каких-либо величин, параметров (в том числе в математическом смысле)...

Получается, что слеш — это не просто косая черта, это замена союза или предлога. В этом случае, по логике конечно же, следующее после слеша слово ну никак не может быть написано с прописной (если только это не имя собственное: *Фолклендские/Мальвинские острова, Дж/Кл*).

Одиночные слова:
*Слитное/раздельное* = Слитное и раздельное = Слитное или раздельное;
*Точка/запятая* = Точка или запятая;
*Тире/двоеточие* = Тире или двоеточие.

Единицы измерения:
*М/с* (скорость) = Метр в секунду;
*Км/ч* (скорость) = Километр в час;
*М/с²* (ускорение) = Метр на секунду в квадрате = Метр в секунду за секунду.

[Косая черта](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=60#pp60)

Comment: А если я, что-то написав, хочу показать, что человек может использовать либо 1-й вариант, либо 2-й, то надо вторую опцию с большой буквы писать? Например: *По-моему / По моему мнению, это надо сделать по-Серёжиному, а не по-дяди-Петиному.*

Comment: Спасибо за оценку и принятие ответа! Но — читайте же внимательнее: *следующее после слеша слово... не может быть написано с прописной... если только это не имя собственное...* Правильно: *По-моему / **п**о моему мнению...* Это равнозначно такому оформлению: "По-моему мнению..." или "**п**о моему мнению..."?